# jquery custom keycode trigger not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, keypress, keystroke

I want to send keystrokes on the selected element like this:

```
$(":input").click(function(){
    $(this).trigger("keydown", [{
        preventDefault:function(){},
        keyCode:9,
        shiftKey: true
    }]);
});

//wants to send Shift+Tab keystroke on input click
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NYwCT/.

Comment: So WHAT is the problem?? Could you please clarify what you want and what is currently happening?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot send keystrokes. It currently triggers any functions that are bound, but does not execute the relevant thing at browser level (what about a script sending ALT+F4?).

If you want to focus the input before the clicked one, you can use `.prev()` (previous sibling): http://jsfiddle.net/NYwCT/1/.

```
$(":input").click(function(){
    $(this).prev().focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not fire the actual event

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.shiftKey = true;
press.keyCode = 9;
$(this).trigger(press);
```

you could also try this plug-in: [fn.sendkeys](http://bililite.com/blog/2008/08/20/the-fnsendkeys-plugin/) or [jwerty](https://keithamus.github.io/jwerty/)